# inherit background-color from following div tag

Tags: html, css, joomla

this is my html

```
<div id = "main">
  <div id = "one">some text</div>
  <div id = "two">two text</div>
</div>
```

As I'm using joomla to create website. So "two" is changing color for every page and so that I would like to set the background-color of "one" to be the same as that of "two". How can I do that?

**Edit**

If I have to set inherited background-color from #main then

I would set

```
#main{background-color: red;}
#one{background-color: inherit;}
```

Like this I would like to set inherited color from #two.

Comment: what do you mean by `set the background-color as "two" to "one".` ?

Comment: #two{background-color: red;} and #one should be inherited from two.

Comment: what is wrong with #two, #one {background-color: red;}

Comment: @epoch #two is changing color for every page so #one must be inherited from #two.

Comment: what construct is making them change color? you can just apply the same logic to #one as well

Answer (score 0):

The second tag has no inherent relationship to the first apart from being a child of `#main`, as I understood you can do this by setting them both to the same color, or setting the `#main` div color

```
div#one, div#two {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Apart from that, you specified that `#two` changes color on every page, just inherit the color from `#main`.

check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/Xkvwx/) to see how it works

Comment: but I couldn't inherit color from main in my site by some reason.

Comment: @C-Link, then there has to be some other problem, please see my fiddle

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to use class and set the css for that class. For example

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="one" class="bg">some text</div>
    <div id="two" class="bg">two text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg {
    background-color:red;
}
```

This way you can use jQuery to just switch the color of the 'bg' class and both will inherit the same background-color.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pqvGV/

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using jquery.

html

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="one">some text</div>
    <div id="two">two text</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#two {
background-color:red;
}
```

jquery

```
var newColor = $('#two').css("background-color");
$('#one').css('background-color', newColor);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swapnilvathare/kLUx6